# Lightweight framework

Tags: theme-development, themes, framework

I am looking for a lightweight and fast wordpress framework to create simple 5-6 pages websites. I tried to create one myself but never had enough time. I also used premium themes but they are too heavy. I want a small understandable framework to stick to and extend its functionality with plugins, I also want to code it easily. Which framework is superfast, light and programmer-friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the Genesis framework by Studiopress: http://my.studiopress.com/themes/genesis/

They are widely used so there is a lot of resources available and good support on their website.